# Python: ttk cannot be installed

Tags: python, tkinter, installation, ttk

Although I have downloaded `ttk` from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyttk/ and installed it using:

```
python setup.py install
```

and got:

[image]

I still can't run my script which uses ttk:

```
from Tkinter import ttk
ImportError: cannot import name ttk
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think `ttk` is installed as a top-level import. Try

```
import ttk
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk
```